# Phonegap: Is there a way to get JSON data from an external url?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

Actually am kinda disappointed as I tried many things and checked out many articles but non worked out for me.

```
function demo() {
console.log("Booooooooooooommmmmmmmmmm");
tokenV = document.getElementById("tokenString").value;
var urlF = "https://***********.com/connect/api.php?action=2&token="+tokenV;

const myHeaders = new Headers();

const myRequest = new Request(urlF, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'default',
});

fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

}
```

I have already whitlist the domain inside my config file, am using phonegap CL latest version. I'm trying to connect to an api which will out put json.encode data if token were right.
Error output:

```
(index):50 Fetch failed loading: GET https://*******.com/connect/api.php.............
```

Another way I tried using cordova fetch plugin still failed:

```
function demo() {
            console.log("Booooooooooooommmmmmmmmmm");
            tokenV = document.getElementById("tokenString").value;
            var urlF = "https://*********.com/api.php?action=2&token="+tokenV;
            console.log("nowww1");
            cordovaFetch(urlF, {
                  method : 'GET',
                  headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'CordovaFetch 1.0.0'
                  },
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                }).then(function(json) {
                    console.log('parsed json', json);
                }).catch(function(ex) {
                    console.log('parsing failed', ex);
                });
            }
```

Error out put:

```
Error: exec proxy not found for :: FetchPlugin :: fetch (index):118 parsing failed TypeError: Network request failed
```

I can change the out put as I want but show me away to get the data from an external server???

Thank you

Comment: try to test your external server endpoint from tools like postman.

Comment: IF I check here: https://reqbin.com/ , adding my url and with get method it looks fine and getting back my page @PharsaThapa

Comment: Are you sure your token is encoded in URL? Apparently, it should be defined in header rather than on Url